# Show that $\dim(U) + \dim(V) = n +1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be the subspace of the even polynomials and $V$ the subspace of the non polynomials.

Show that $\dim(U) + \dim(V) = n +1$

My try:

Well I started to find a basis $B_1$ and $B_2$ for $U$ and $V$ 
respectively because the dimension of the basis has the same dimension as $U$ and $V$

$B_1 = \{(1,0,...,0),(0,0,1,0,...,0),...,(0,...,1)\}$

My trouble is that I don´t know how I could find $\dim(B_1)$

Comment: What is a non polynomial?  Odd polynomial?  And I assume that $U$ and $V$ live in the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$?  (And the ground field must be of characteristic $\ne 2$, otherwise the equality doesn't hold.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\textsf K$ be a field. Fix $p(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\cdots+a_nt^n\in \textsf{K}[t]$ an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$. Notice that $p(t)$ can be written as
$$p(t)=(b_0+b_1t+\cdots+b_nt^n)+(c_0+c_1t+\cdots+c_nt^n)$$
where $b_i=0$ whenever $i$ is odd and $c_i=0$ whenever $i$ is even. This means $p(t)\in\textsf{U}+\textsf{V}$ and hence the vector space of all the polynomials with coefficients in $\textsf K$ with degree at most $n$ is the same as $\textsf{U}+\textsf{V}$.

Now, suppose we have a polynomial $q(t)$ in $\textsf{U}\cap\textsf{V}$. Then, $q(t)=q(-t)=-q(t)$ which means $2q(t)=0$ and hence $q(t)$ is the zero polynomial. Thus $\textsf{U}\cap\textsf{V}=\{0\}$ and therefore

$$n+1=\dim(\textsf{U}+\textsf{V})=\dim(\textsf{U})+\dim(\textsf{V})-\underbrace{\dim(\textsf{U}\cap\textsf{V})}_0=\dim(\textsf{U})+\dim(\textsf{V})$$